# Tricky C exercise related to pointers. Need help in understanding the solution

Tags: c

Consider the following code:

```
int *foo (int x) {
int a[2];
a[0] = x;
a[1] = x + 1;
return a;
}
…
int *p1 = foo(2);
int *p2 = foo(3);
```

At the conclusion of this code snippet, what are the values of each of the following? (answer is given)

```
 p1[0] = 3
 p1[1] = 4
 p2[0] = 3
 p2[1] = 4
```

Since a is allocated on the stack, the memory does not remain allocated when the call returns and may be reused by something else. In this case, since foo(3) is called immediately after foo(2) at the same call depth (i.e. they use the same stack space), they will both return the same pointer– i.e. p1 is equal to p.

I did not understand the above explanation. What does it really mean? Why we have exact same values for p2 and p1? I know that you cannot return a pointer to a local variable in C..but I do not understand why p2 and p1 has same values ....

Comment: You *can* return a local pointer, it's just that the memory is not guaranteed to hold its value ("may be reused by something else"). In this case, `foo(3)` "reuses" and overwrites the memory used by `foo(2)`. Since `p1` and `p2` are pointers, you get the value upon request, resulting in the given answers.

Comment: The second function call is overwriting the previous values '2' & '3' which were on the stack to '3' and '4'. And 'p1' and 'p2' are pointing to the same stack locations.

Comment: Yet another question that isn't about the C language and how to write software using it, but is rather about how the stack works in specific implementations of C ... the only purpose of which is to write exploits. If schools and instructors that are teaching this stuff are claiming to teach the C programming language, they are committing fraud.

Comment: @JimBalter Not particularly, no. They have to pick a language in order to get anything done, but the point of most introductory programming classes is teaching students how computers work, not teaching them that specific language. In this case, while he's not learning anything about C, he *is* learning something about how memory works in most operating systems, regardless of language used. As long as that is what they claim to do (and usually it is), it isn't fraud.

Comment: @Wlerin Yes, particularly. You have demonstrated in your comments that you don't understand what the C language is, what "undefined behavior" is, what the C standard says and how it relates to the C language ... I was on the C standards committee and have programmed in C since the mid-70s ... I'll take my own judgment of the accuracy of my statement over yours, thank you.

Comment: @JimBalter But you're not in education *or* a lawyer... noted. (Neither am I, ofc.)

Comment: @Wlerin " but the point of most introductory programming classes is teaching students how computers work, not teaching them that specific language" -- **try reading what I wrote**: IF schools and instructors that are teaching this stuff are **claiming to teach the C programming language** ... sheesh.

Comment: @Wlerin But sophism. I *am* a language lawyer, and have been an instructor. I'm done with you.

Comment: @JimBalter Same to you. (For both comments.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a pointer to automatic storage variables (variables scoped to functions) outside its scope is undefined, which is exactly why you should *never* do it, and *never* depend on its behavior.

However, if you want to peel back the cover on the compiler/machine/os, the reason is that the automatic storage happens to be allocated at the same address for the two function calls.

An example...

```
#include "stdio.h"

int* foo(int x) {
  int a[2];

  printf("&a[0] = %p\n", &a[0]);
  printf("&a[1] = %p\n\n", &a[1]);

  a[0] = x;
  a[1] = x + 1;

  return a;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  printf("foo(2)\n");
  int* p1 = foo(2);

  printf("foo(3)\n");
  int* p2 = foo(3);

  printf("p1[0] = %i\n", p1[0]);
  printf("p1[1] = %i\n\n", p1[1]);

  printf("p2[0] = %i\n", p2[0]);
  printf("p2[1] = %i\n", p2[1]);

  return 0;
}
```

outputs...

```
foo(2)
&a[0] = 0x7fff4dd0f054
&a[1] = 0x7fff4dd0f058

foo(3)
&a[0] = 0x7fff4dd0f054
&a[1] = 0x7fff4dd0f058

p1[0] = 3
p1[1] = 4

p2[0] = 3
p2[1] = 4
```

So, `&a[0]` and `&a[1]` have the same addresses in both `foo(2)` and `foo(3)`.

What's happening is that when you enter a function, it generally creates a stack frame (by decrementing the stack pointer on x86).  This allocates memory on the stack for automatic storage variables.  When you leave the function, the stack frame is destroyed (and the stack pointer returned to its original value).  So if you enter the same function again, you generally use the same memory for the stack frame (stack pointer is decremented to same value as last call to function).

Comment: +1 for an intelligent response that actually addresses the question.

Comment: *the stack frame is destroyed (and the stack pointer returned to its original value)* -- the word "destroyed" together with the word "and" is misleading. "destruction" of the stack frame just consists of resetting the stack pointer; nothing in the stack frame is changed (until it gets reused later). That's why the values of `a` are still what they were set to within `foo` when they are accessed in `main`.

Comment: I agree, *destroyed* was a bad choice of word.  The frame is no longer *live*, but it would be expensive to actually reset the memory in the frame, and there's no major benefit.  It's completely up to the compiler to do what's best though, which is one of the reasons I think it's left undefined.  Slightly unrelated, but the compiler is also free to add things like canary bytes to check for stack corruption.

Comment: It's left undefined because it's a scope violation that makes no sense within C's semantics. If the C standard did define it, the only reasonable thing it could do is to require the compiler to issue a diagnostic, but in the general case that requires escape analysis, which it is not "in the spirit of C" to impose on compilers (and the C standards committee is dominated by compiler vendors who would never accept it). As for what the compiler is free to do ... it doesn't even need to implement a contiguous stack; frames could be a linked list of heap memory, for instance.

Answer (score 7):

it is undefined behavior, your program might crash too.

The local variable is stored on the stack and its life time is only with in the scope of the function.

In your case, the program is reusing the same location the next time , so your values are overwritten, but it is not always going to be same and never return address of local variable.

Comment: Since these are being pushed onto and read from the stack, is it really undefined? I agree you shouldn't do it, in general, but isn't the stack pre-allocated? i.e. nothing outside this program is going to be writing to that space, so what you do here is the only thing that can affect it.

Comment: Ah, fun. "stack" and "heap" aren't actually defined in C either. It's just how most operating systems behave.

Comment: Yes it's really undefined

Comment: @Wlerin I have rouble imagining what you thought "undefined behavior" meant, if it wasn't as described in the C standard.  And this isn't about operating systems, it's about C implementations. The same OS that runs a C implementation that uses a stack can also run, for instance, a C interpreter that allocates stack frames and checks for invalid operations like this.

Comment: @JimBalter I wasn't aware that the C Standard says nothing about the stack and heap when I wrote the first comment.

Comment: @Wlerin So you just made up something in your head and based your judgment of whether it's undefined behavior on that. Around here (the [C] section of SO), people actually bother to become familiar with the C standard before they go making claims about what it says. That there's no stack in the definition of C is pretty basic.

Comment: @JimBalter And now I've learned something new. Everyone wins.

Comment: It's funny that someone thinks he's "everyone". All we have here is a distraction from a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

After each function call memory is allocated on stack for function variables and stack pointer is moved forward. After function execution stack memory is not erased for efficiency reasons and all data stays there. So if you call same function second time and leave some variables uninitialized you can find some funny values from last function call. Every array in C is stored as a big chunk of memory where elements are found by shifting pointer.
As for you question: foo returns pointer to integer, which is actually a memory address.
After foo(2) p1 will store some address for example 0x00. Adding braces [] with index to a integer pointer means to add an integer size * index to a memory address. We may add any random index to pointer and try to get data from there. If we get lucky and memory is readable - we will have some garbage data. After first function call

```
p1 points to a stack array and values are:
p1[0] == 2;
p2[1] == 3;
p1 == 0x00; (for example)
```

Function is executed and it returns stack pointer back. Next function call foo(3) gets same memory chunk on stack. Second call rewrites variables with new values. After second call we get:

```
p2[0] == 3;
p2[1] == 4;
p2 == 0x00; (same memory address)
```

The problem is that p1 points to same memory address on stack. If you call any other function - both p1 and p2 will be changed again, because same region of stack will be reused again.

Answer (score 0):

In your function foo() you have a local variable and your are trying to return the address of the local variable. Don't your compiler throw the below error:

```
warning: function returns address of local variable
```

If you have to get the answer you have posted then you need to make the array `int a[2]` global.
Else we have an undefined behavior here.

Comment: a) Not all compilers generate that warning. b) You're completely missing the point, which is that this is an exercise and the the OP is supposed to figure out what the results are and why. That it's undefined behavior does not prevent incompetent instructors from demanding that their students figure out how specific implementations work.

Comment: @JimBalter In the question I see the (answer is given) and see some  outputs(3,4,3,4). Yes we see undefined behavior here but how can someone give outputs for this which is completely misleading.

Comment: The behavior is undefined because the C standard doesn't define it, not because of what happens. Undefined behavior is an **abstract** descriptor, not a **concrete** one. It refers to behavior that isn't defined by the C standard. There are no *instances* or *examples* of "undefined behavior" ... *anything* can be the result of undefined behavior. As for "how can someone give outputs" -- because there is **actual, real, behavior** of **actual, real, implementations**. The C standard doesn't define what they are, but they still exist, and people use them to exploit buggy programs, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Stack unwind while returning from the function call will release the memory allocated for the array. That memory is no longer available. The behavior is undefined.

Comment: And how does that explain to the OP what the OP wants to know (and what his/her instructor wants)?